# Why no other company is producing Bitcoin ASIC except bitmain?

Tags: asic

Except bitfury and 1-2 Chinese companies that looks fake or just a copy of Antminer.

Nobody in Western produces miners?

Why?

Comment: There used to be spoondoliestech but bitmain didn't let them earn money AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is merely a hypothesis.

The difficulty of mining difficulty was going up so quickly that any miner you bought quickly lost its value but if the value of bitcoin also went up, you could barely come out ahead in some situations before it wasn't worth mining anymore.  Some companies started charging for their miners before they had even built them or finished designing them yet, but as they were trying to stay ahead of the increase in bitcoin difficulty, they fell behind and eventually had to give money back, got sued, etc as they didn't give people what they were ordering.

Now its easier for companies who can do that to simply mine the coins for themselves.  Why sell it to customers who will just complain they didn't come out ahead when you can just use your hardware yourself and come out way ahead since you're doing it at cost.  Now it seems that the average person who wants to take part in such things need only purchase cloud mining contracts as it works out better for the hardware makers.

Comment: Sad, but seems true.